# How can i get transaction details in paypal

Tags: php, paypal

I am working on a web in which buyer make his payment on paypal website. the transaction is working perfectly but after that how can i get the transaction details like address, name, amount etc. to store admin database

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Paypal IPN https://www.paypal.com/au/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/acc/ipn-info-outside

This will return all sorts of details, including a confirmation on whether the transaction has succeeded or not.  This is especially useful if you are immediately delivering digital goods.

Comment: As you said i have enabled IPN . now how to get that details ?

Answer (score 0):

As they mentioned, IPN would be your best option for this.  [Here's the latest documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/).

Alternatively, if you just need to get details at a random time outside of checkout you can use the [GetTransactionDetails API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/).